# How i can start nwb in https?

Tags: javascript, npm, https, server, nwb

I have this package.json script:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "nwb build-react-component",
    "clean": "nwb clean-module && nwb clean-demo",
    "start": "nwb serve-react-demo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 3000",
    "test": "nwb test-react",
    "test:coverage": "nwb test-react --coverage",
    "test:watch": "nwb test-react --server"
  },
```

If i use npm start this rune me server at http://127.0.0.1:3000

How i can run https?

I try `HTTPS=true npm start`
but its not working :(

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via [`devServer.https`](https://github.com/insin/nwb/blob/master/docs/Configuration.md#dev-server-configuration) configuration, either in your `nwb.config.js` module…

```
{
  devServer: {
    https: true
  }
}
```

…or via the CLI:

```
nwb serve-react-demo --devServer.https
```

Answer (score 0):

config in nwb.config.js

```
module.exports = { 
 devServer: {
  host: "sso-admin-presit.hktdc.com",
  port: 443,
  https: true   
 },
}
```